# ListView adapter to display certain fields

Tags: android, android-listview

I have `ListView` that is populated like so:

```
ArrayList<MyFullDataClass> myFullDataClassList = Utilities.getDataFromSQLite(getActivity()); // populate list from SQLite
ArrayAdapter<MyFullDataClass> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyFullDataClass>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, MyFullDataClassList);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

MyFullDataClass contains many things: Name, address, phone, email, web site, etc. So as it is, each row of the list contains all of this information. It's a little busy. I would like to make it so that each row in the list contains only, say, name and email (and then touching the row would popup with all information in MyFullDataClass)

I could do this by creating a class, call it MyPartialDataClass, that contains fields for only name and email, then create an `ArrayList<MyPartialDataClass>` and copy data from myFullDataClassList to myPartialDataClassList and use this partial class for the adapter. (Then when a row is clicked, use myFullDataClassList.)

Not particularly elegant, but it would work.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a need to have two separate classes which ultimately hold the same information.

Having one class to hold necessary information is fine, unless you absolutely need minute efficiency gains of having two classes. What I would do is  make your Adapter take a `MyFullDataClass` object list, but only populate the views with name and email.

From there, you can listen for an `onClick` event on your Adapter and pass the `MyFullDataClass` object associated with the clicked view to a fragment which will display the rest of the information associated with the `MyFullDataClass` object (i.e. the fragment will display address, phone, etc in addition to name and email).

You wouldn't make two separate tables in a database to hold parts of the same information. You would select what rows/properties from each entry that you need. The same concept applies here, IMO.

Comment: _make your Adapter take a MyFullDataClass object list, but only populate the views with name and email._ I don't know how to do this other than creating another class.

Comment: Ah, I see you're using an `ArrayAdapter`. In this case, it would be best to extend and create your own custom Adapter. That way, you'd be able to use custom views in your `ListView`; you could make your view only display name and email.

Comment: I've implemented a custom adapter [similar to this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown_custom)